# matlab: fmincon, pass variables into nonlcon

Tags: function, matlab, variables, octave, minimize

I know its a stupid question, but I have no idea how to solve it... Lets say I have something like:

```
x = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@mycon)
```

and later on :

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
c = ...     
ceq = ...
```

How to pass additional variables into `@mycon`, such as

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x, variable)
if variable == 1 
    c = ...     
    ceq = ... 
else   
    c = ...     
    ceq = ... 
end
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `mycon` as anonymous function:

```
   x = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@(xx)mycon(xx,variable))
```

Note that `variable` is fixed at the moment the `fmincon` line is called.