# Adding non linear conditions to matlab optimization package depending on variables not being optimized

Tags: matlab

I am using the global maximization toolbox to maximize the following function:

```
    function x = NameOfFunction (w1, w2, w3, a, b, c, Structure1, Structure2, Structure3)
```

where I am minimizing `x` by changing the values of `w1`, `w2`, and `w3`. The remaining parameters are constants and structures containing data. The value of `x`, as well as the three `w` variables depend on the data that is fed into the function via the structures.

The function returns `x` which is the mean of 180 values that are calculated in the process of running `NameOfFunction`.

I am wondering how I could add a constraint on the standard deviation of the 180 values.  I am not interested in minimizing both the mean and the standard deviation, but rather to minimize `x`(the mean), while allowing standard deviation to be no greater than some specific value.  I know how to add constraints to the decision variables (ie. `w1`, `w2`, `w3`), but have no idea how to do so for a value like the standard deviation.

EDIT: More detail, per Werner's suggestion:

```
%the functions is f(w) rather than f(x)

%constraints:
Aeq = [1 1 1];
beq = 1;
lb = .10 * [1 1 1];
ub = .8 * [1 1 1];

w = [weight1, weight2, weight3];     
wstart = randn(3,1);

options = optimset('Algorithm','interior-point');

% function handle for the objective function (note that variables 
% aa through hh are additional parameters that the solver does not modify): 
h = @(w)NameOfFunction(w(1),w(2),w(3), aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh);

% problem structure:
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',wstart,'objective',h,...'
'Aeq',Aeq,'beq',beq,'options',options,'lb',lb,'ub',ub);

gs = GlobalSearch;
run(gs,problem)
```

I'm running a `GlobalSearch` using `fmincon`.

---

7/16/2013, After implementing `nonlcon` I was able to achieve what I tried to do.  (I have a follow-up question, which I put on the bottom of this post).  Here's what I did:

I added another function (`StdConstraintFunction`) as discussed.  So now I have the following:

```
stdMax = 0.01;
h = @(w)NameOfFunction(w(1),w(2),w(3),aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg);
StdConstraint = @(w)StdConstraintFunction(w(1),w(2),w(3),aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg,stdMax);
```

where `StdConstraintFunction` is a modified version of `NameOfFunction` that calculates the standard deviation rather than the mean.

The last line in the two functions is the only thing that is different in the body of the functions.

In `NameOfFunction`, the last line is:

```
ReturnVariable = -1 * (nanmedian([vect1]));
%note: I added the -1 multiplication to search for the maximum rather than minimum
```

The last line in `StdConstraintFunction` is:

```
ReturnVariable = (std([vect1]) - stdMax);
ceq = []; 
%ceq is a required variable that is supposed to return the equality non-linear
%constraint; here it is blank because I don't have one.  The optimization 
%would produce an error if I exclude it
```

and my problem setup is:

```
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',xstart,'objective',h,'Aeq',Aeq,'beq',beq,'options',options,'lb',lb,'ub',ub,'nonlcon',StdConstraint);
```

@Werner: If you want to post this as the answer to the question, I will gladly accept it as the official answer.  Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: This is more an issue of understanding how to create the problem than how to program it. You have an optimization problem and you want to add constrain that depends non linearly on `x` var. It would be better if you improve your question with information of what kind of optimization you are doing (linear, etc.), how you are using the matlab optimization toolbox and so on.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you for your reply.  I have added some additional details to my post above.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Great, now your question is good enough. I will try to work it out, but I don't remember this stuff, there is quite a while I did this subject on grad school haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solving optimizations problems with non-linear conditions depending only on variables being optimized

Using matlab fmincon [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html?s_tid=doc_12b):

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options)
```

Where:

> nonlcon:The function that computes the nonlinear inequality constraints c(x)≤ 0 and the nonlinear equality constraints ceq(x) = 0. nonlcon accepts a vector x and returns the two vectors c and ceq. c is a vector that contains the nonlinear inequalities evaluated at x, and ceq is a vector that contains the nonlinear equalities evaluated at x. nonlcon should be specified as a function handle to a file or to an anonymous function, such as mycon:
>
> x = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@mycon)
>
> where mycon is a MATLAB function such as

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
c = ...     % Compute nonlinear inequalities at x.
ceq = ...   % Compute nonlinear equalities at x.
```

> If the gradients of the constraints can also be computed and the GradConstr option is 'on', as set by
>
> options = optimoptions('fmincon','GradConstr','on')
>
> then nonlcon must also return, in the third and fourth output arguments, GC, the gradient of c(x), and GCeq, the gradient of ceq(x). GC and GCeq can be sparse or dense. If GC or GCeq is large, with relatively few nonzero entries, save running time and memory in the interior-point algorithm by representing them as sparse matrices. For more information, see [Nonlinear Constraints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-constraints.html#brhkghv-16).

So, what you will need to do in order to add the non linear constrain is to use the nonlcon function that will return c with the standard deviation from w's values. It may be accomplished using an anonymous function:

```
nonlcon = @(x) std(x) - std_lim;
```

which means std(x) <= std_lim, where x are the variables passed to matlab to be optimized, in this case the `wstart` variable, but at the kth iteration. Of course, instead of std you may use whatever you may want, i.e `x(1)^2 + x(2)^3 - sin(x(3))`, supposing you have three variables being optimized.

And then change your code to:

```
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',wstart,'objective',h,...
'Aeq',Aeq,'beq',beq,'options',options,'lb',lb,'ub',ub,'nonlcon',nonlcon);
```

**Note**: If you don't have one or more of the above extra variables, i.e. linear lower boundary `lb`, just don't add it to `createOptimProblem`.

### Solving optimizations problems with non-linear conditions also depending on variables that are not being optimized

In this particular problem, the problem variables to be optimized (w) are not the only variables needed to calculate the standard deviation as noticed by @Mr. Kinn, so there is a need to feed the matlab non linear conditions function with extra variables that are not being optimized in each iteration. In order to do so, we alter our anonymous function handle to:

```
StdConstraint = @(w)StdConstraintFunction(w(1),w(2),w(3),aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg,stdMax);
```

which is a function handle with one input variable, called w, fed via matlab internal code with the variables being optimized. In this presented solution, this variable is fed as three arguments to a matlab file function called StdConstrainFunction, which will also receive variables `aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,stdMax` from the environment where the `StdConstraint` handle function was created, so they will not be modified by the matlab internal routines during optimization.

There, the variables are used to calculate the non linear condition to be respected, remembering that, as said by the matlab documentation, the values returned by the non linear condition function must be two: `c,ceq`. The first returned output, `c`, are the conditions which must be lesser than zero when they are being respected, o.c. when out of bounds. The second output `ceq`are the non linear conditions equation that must be respected.

You may adapt this particular solution for your problem, just by changing the arguments passed to the handle function used as non linear constrain.

[Consider also seeing this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641590/matlab-fmincon-pass-variables-into-nonlcon?rq=1)

Comment: Since I didn't run this code, and just wrote pseudo-code, I am not sure if the code is 100% right… If you have problems running it, please tell me so I can fix it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your very thorough reply!  I tried running the code, but got a `Failure in initial call to fmincon with user-supplied problem structure. ` error.  I tried implementing the non-linear constraint as an anonymous function like this: `nonlcon = @(h) std(h) - 0.01;`.  (I also tried using `w` instead of `h`).  My objective function returns a single variable (which is the mean of 180 values that are calculated within the body of the objective function).  Will this approach produce the std dev of the 180 values?  I'm not sure I understand how this code can accomplish that...

Comment: (continuation of above comment). It seems like the code above is trying to find the standard deviation associated with the decision variables and not the final mean calculation.  My objective function creates a local variable that stores a structure containing the 180 values used in calculating the mean (which is the final output of the function).  Is there a way to indicate that I want to control for the standard deviation of the 180 values in the structure?  Please let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: I will answer this with more details tomorrow, but you may try the following: instead of `…'nonlcon',nonlcon)`, do `…'nonlcon',nonlcon(~,your_180_values_variable))`, and change nonlcon to `@(a,b) = std(b)-std_lim;`.

Comment: If you prefer, you may do exactly the way you did for the `NameOfFunction` (writing a .m function file and calling it), for this purpose, suppose you've called it `StdContrain.m`, then you will do `contrainHandle = @(w) StdConstrain(w(1),w(2),w(3), aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh,max_std);` and inside the `StdContrain.m` you do as you do on `NameOfFunction.m`, but instead to calculate the std value. But don't forget afterwards to subtract it from `max_std` input!

Comment: And you were right, the code I wrote used only the 3 variables, I didn't notice that there was more variables on the problem…

Comment: In reference to your `StdContrain.m` script, wouldn't this produce a second optimization problem that looks at the standard deviation in isolation?  In other words, how do I ensure that `NameOfFunction` and `StdContrain` produce the same set of data (a shared mean and a shared standard deviation between them)?

Comment: Also, the 180-value vector (I'll call it `vect1` for ease of reference) is dynamically created during the execution of the objective function.  The values generated in `vect1` depend on the values that the optimizer assigns to `w1`, `w2`, and `w3`, and so, by setting a limit on the standard deviation of `vect1`, the optimizer would inherently alter the 180 values generated for `vect1`, as well as the final mean output of the function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33520/discussion-between-werner-and-mr-kinn)

Comment: I edited my post above to reflect our discussion yesterday. If you would like to post a part of my post update as the answer to this question, I will gladly accept it as the answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just did it. I think that a title like: "Adding non linear conditions to matlab optimization package depending on variables not being optimized." would be more proper to your question, since it meets a more general situation that people may have trouble with.